# Error in transport phase

Tags: content-delivery, publishing, deployer, transport

I'm trying to configure XPM in my Tridion installation, but I have found a problem publishing a Page. The error appears in transport phase and shows the following information:

> Transport failed: Unable to copy and rename C:\content\incoming\tcm_0-36-66560.Content.zip.busy on destination.

The configuration of my Publication Target is (the destination location folder is on the same server as the Content Manager):

```
Protocol: Local file system
Location: C:\content\incoming\
```

My `cd_transport` has the following attributes:

```
<WorkFolder Location="C:\content\incoming\" NotificationBatchSize="10"/>
```

I have installed the Deployer as a Windows Service and it runs fine (on the same server as the Content Manager). This is the Deployer configuration:

```
...
<Queue>
    <Location Path="C:\content\incoming\" WindowSize="20" Workers="10" Cleanup="true" Interval="2s"/>
...
```

The logs don't give me more information about the error so I'm lost.

Do you know what could be the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you **edit** your question and provide a bit more detail on your setup, are the `C:\content\incoming\ ` folders mentioned one and the same (i.e on the same server)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have installed CMS and CD as the single box, I would recommend keeping the path as different for both transport and deployer:

cd_transport_conf.xml

```
   <!-- The WorkFolder element defines the location where temporary files are stored. -->
    <WorkFolder Location="./transactions" NotificationBatchSize="10"/>
```

Comment: @netosone if the answer was useful, can you consider upvoting and accepting it, please see https://tridion.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers for more details.